# WP_MAIL attachment

Tags: wordpress, attachment

I have a problem with wp_mail function in Wordpress. I need to use attachment which is on this adress:
http://student.michalfolprecht.com/wp-content/plugins/commerce/invoice.php

It is PDF document which I need to attach to wp_mail function. I've already try to use this code:

```
$attachments = array('http://student.michalfolprecht.com/wp-content/plugins/commerce/invoice.php')
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign physical path of the attachment file instead of relative/absolute URL

for example

$attachments = array(WP_CONTENT_DIR."/uploads/2014/07/YOUR_FILE_NAME.EXT");

Hope this helps